# Nested event listener does not work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I am refactoring my old code to make it more adjustable to the newest features. I am writing a class that describes what can be done with DOM Node and one of the functions does not work properly. In the code below 2 nested event listeners that are responsible for changing coordinates of the element on the page, when the element is pressed it creates "mousemove" listener that runs each time mouse changes it location, and when mouse is released it stays in new place. The issue is that when mouse is pressed mousemove event fires once, when mouse is released it fires again, but the element itself does not change its location while mouse is dragged. How to fix this?

```
      video: {
        multiple: true,
        types: [
          {
            description: "Video",
            accept: {
              "video/*": [
                ".mp4",
                ".flv",
                ".vob",
                ".avi",
                ".wmv",
                ".mpg",
                ".gif",
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },

      SVG: {
        multiple: true,
        types: [{ description: "SVG", accept: { "image/*": [".svg"] } }],
      },
    };
    this.style_elem = function () {
      this.isActive
        ? (this.element.style.border = "2px solid #30C5FF")
        : (this.element.style.border = "none");
      this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    };

    this.URL_s = async function (options) {
      let fileHandle = await window.showOpenFilePicker(options);
      const fileArray = fileHandle.map(async (file) => {
        return file.getFile();
      });
      const files = await Promise.all(fileArray);
      const url_string = files.map((file) => {
        return URL.createObjectURL(file);
      });
      return url_string;
    };

    this.changePos = function (e) {
      this.element.style.top = e.clientY - this.shiftY + "px";
      this.element.style.left = e.clientX - this.shiftX + "px";

    };

    this.init = async function () {
      const URL = await this.URL_s(this.options.image);
      let img_arr = URL.map((url) => {
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = url;
        let container = document.createElement("div");
        container.style.width = "fit-content";
        container.style.position = "absolute";
        container.appendChild(img);
        this.element=container;
        return container;
      });

      img_arr.forEach((img) => {
        img.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            this.element = e.currentTarget;
            this.shiftX = e.clientX - img.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            this.shiftY = e.clientY - img.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            this.style_elem();
            this.changePos(e);
            this.element.addEventListener("mousemove",this.changePos(e));
          });
        
          img.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
            this.style_elem();
            this.element.removeEventListener("mousemove",this.changePos(e));
          });

        document
          .getElementById("ifr")
          .contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(img);
      });
    };

    this.init();
  }






}
```

Comment: Not sure if you understand the code right. It attaches 2 event listeners to the img Node object. Onmousedown it attaches mousemove listener to the document and runs the function that changes the top, left coordinates of the element. When onmouseup it removes mousemove listener.

Comment: Yep you’re right.  The mismatched indentation got me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `mousemove` event listener. It should be added to the `document` object, not the element, to handle fast mouse movements. Also, use `bind(this)` to ensure this inside `changePos` refers to the correct object. This should work:

```js
img_arr.forEach((img) => {
  img.onmousedown = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.element = e.currentTarget;
    this.shiftX = e.clientX - img.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    this.shiftY = e.clientY - img.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    this.style_elem();
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.changePos.bind(this));
  };

  img.onmouseup = (e) => {
    this.style_elem();
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.changePos.bind(this));
  };

  document.getElementById("ifr").contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(img);
});
```

Comment: Now its working only when mouse is out of the document space.

Comment: Thank you, i have been tinkering with code that you gave me and its working now.

Comment: Glad I could help :)